# Rails 7.0.4 Active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using Rails 7.0.4 in API mode and Active Storage for image uploading. When I update my server, my old images only show the URL and the image itself is not displayed. I'm not using any bucket. How can I make the old images display again?But when a user add new images after server update they are displayed

I've tried looking for a solution but couldn't find any. It seems like a problem with Active Storage, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've also checked the logs, but didn't see any errors related to this issue.

Any suggestions on how to make the old images display again would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what's the url you're using for passing your images through the API

Comment: http://64.227.136.4/rails/active_storage/blobs/red…9401e876b77837a3f9de8f9741972700f48f81b/img-1.jpg i am getting this image url in reponse it was working in previous release but whenever i add new release it dont display old imaghes just show this url'